# Weird formatting of List headers in Chrome

Tags: trello

This weird thing has popped up for me when I launch Trello in Chrome. I can't replicate this problem in Firefox.

Screenshot: http://d.pr/i/OlfT

It looks like it's waiting for me to rename the list, but I don't want to, and I have tried everything and it won't go away.

Comment: Are you running any chrome extensions that would affect trello.com?  If so, does disabling them help?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using and on what platform (Windows, Linux, iPad)?

Comment: @DanielLeCheminant you are right. an extension was causing this.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a Chrome Extension that you have installed.  Disabling the extension will resolve the issue.